# LabView: Icon identification

Tags: reverse-engineering, labview

I'm entirely new to LabView, and as a pet project, I'm trying to recreate a pulse detector. Thing is, the version of the .VI is LabView2010, and I can't open the.VI in LabView2009, so were trying to remake it by looking at the module. I do however, have the image, but since I'm pretty new, I can't identify some of the components used. Below is an image of the .VI, as well as, the parts I don't know encircled with red and enumerated. What exactly are these? Thanks![image]

Comment: You can ask people to convert your VI for you on [the NI forums](http://forums.ni.com/t5/Version-Conversion/bd-p/VersionConversion)

Comment: If you want to recreate the code in a lower version, you will need the specific configuration of the Express VIs (the blue functions). And you will need to know the contents of the 'False' case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I only have limited experience with the specific features in this code, so I don't have exact names, but it should point you in the right direction:

2 is a dynamic data indicator. 
1 converts it to a waveform (it probably appears automatically if you hook up a DDT wire to a WF function.
3 unbundles the data from the waveform. It should be in the waveform palette.

4 is a shift register.

5 is a wait function.

---

In general, I would recommend that you get to learning, as you will need to understand these things to at least that level before you can be proficient.

Also, the NI forums are much more suitable for this type of question and they have many more users. I would suggest if you have such questions which you can't answer yourself, then post them there.

Answer (score 1):

To make a shift register, right click on the edge of the while loop and place a shift register.  The Wait (ms) node is found in the timing functions pallet.  #1 and #3 are found in the waveform generation pallet.  And #2 is a waveform graph that is bound to the output of the filter.  Just right click on the output of the filter and create an Indicator